# Roblox Studio - Each block doesn't have the same value

Tags: lua, roblox

As you can see on this photo: https://gyazo.com/9ca355a460c5602ec073bcbae701dede i clicked on every block. My problem is that every block doens't have the same Value. I want every block when i click at it to go down 1/10 everytime i click and still give me 1 in my backpack pr. click. Right now i can see that the value of the blocks if not the same.

Here is the script for the blocks: https://gyazo.com/b627ae8559b9035f0fdfe88297b13364 (Think the problem is here)

As you can see on this photo the value is 0,8. And the other one downstairs is 0,1 and so on https://gyazo.com/ac5359b7f6a7e123ad31507f4384323d

The damage value is 0.2 as u see here: https://gyazo.com/b9de1795c27eb151caf8db2d79e9f58a

Here is the script for the shovel: 
https://gyazo.com/14b5e675be5644056bda8b24f828ec6a

I would appreciate if u could help me to fix this problem. Tell me if u need more information about this to fix this problem. Hope u understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this line (26) u r generating a random damage value

```
dmg.value = math.random(1, 10)/10
```

Did u try to set it on

```
dmg.value = 1/10
```

?